# Post Json Object from AngularJs to java JAX-RS service

Tags: java, angularjs, jersey

I google this matter for hours but I still cannot find solution.

Here is my java code

```
  @POST
  public String doLogin(User user) {
    System.out.println(" = " + user.getUsername());
    return "";
  }
```

and

```
 @XmlRootElement
  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  public class User {
    String username;

    String password;

    public String getUsername() {
      return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
      this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
      return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
      this.password = password;
    }
  }
```

and here is my AngularJs code

```
 angular.module('notesApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', ['$http', function($http) {
      var self = this;
      self.submit = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/Test/app/login',
            headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data: self.user //forms user object
          })
          .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
          }, function(response) {

          });
      }
  }]);
```

My error message was: 
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class entity.User, and Java type class entity.User, and MIME media type application/json; charset=UTF-8 was not found, as I could not access 'user' Object in java code.

Could you please figure out which part I do wrong? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read from `POST` body and not `Query Params`.

You can use this:

```
  @POST
  public String doLogin( User user) {
    System.out.println(" = " + user.getUsername());
    return "";
  }
```

`@QueryParam` is used to the queryparams which you'll pass as `?user=xyz@gmail.com`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help first. I tried that before and I got this error message. SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class entity.User, and Java type class entity.User, and MIME media type application/json; charset=UTF-8 was not found.

Answer (score 0):

Remove query param You will get a serialized string. deSerialize it to User.

Answer (score 0):

```
@POST
public String doLogin(User user) {
    System.out.println(" = " + user.getUsername());
    return "";
}
```

You are setting the `data` field on your `POST`.  This sets the HTTP *Body*, not an HTTP query param.

Answer (score 0):

Check the browser debugger networking panel to ensure that you are sending what you expect to the server.   will open it and then 'send' your user and look at what is sent.   Does this object look exactly like what User in java expects?